Compare 2 csv based on key column with different rows and columns using Pandas dataframe
I have two different CSV files - old.csv and new.csv. they are with a different number of rows and columns. the CSV files can include numbers, strings, chars, and special characters. For example:
old.csv
 id    round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth seventh
1     2  2021.04      2    45e69     10    16      4565   37       56
2     3  2021.04      4      15    456as  df924     35   4N320     78
4     5  2021.03      4    43!d9    23      26      29     33     09

new.csv
 id round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth
0     1  2021.04      1      14     15      24      40     41
1     2  2021.04      2    45e69    10      16     4565    37
2     3  2021.04      4      15    456as   df924    35    4N320
3     4  2021.03     10      11     20      21     24325   41
5     6  2021.03    4321       9   2#@6     28     34350   41

Now, I want to compare both csv only common rows based on 'id' column (row#1 and row#2) data needs to be compared and output should display difference between 2 rows only
result.csv
 id round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth     seventh

1     2  2021.04      2    45e69    10      16     4565    37      56, NaN
2     3  2021.04      4      15    456as   df924    35    4N320    09,NaN

I have tried to use dataframe compare method but its not working per my need as it requires same number of rows and columns.
Code (with different rows but same columns)
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV files
df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')

#print(df1['id'].iloc[0])
#print(df1['id'].iloc[1])

#df1.iloc[1]

#print(df2['id'].values)
#print(df1['id'].iloc[7])

#if df1['id'].iloc[7] in df2['id'].values :
    #print("\nThis value exists in Dataframe")


for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    #print(row['id'])
    #print(index)
    #print(df1['id'].iloc[index])
    idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
    if df1['id'].iloc[index] in df2['id'].values :
    #print("\nThis value exists in Dataframe")
        #print(df1.loc[index])
        #print(df2.loc[index])
        row_index = df2.index[df2['id'] == df1['id'].iloc[index]].tolist()
        #print(row_index[0])
        #print(index)
        dff= df1.loc[index].compare(df2.loc[row_index[0]])
    print(dff)

output
      self other
name  asqw    as
age      1     4
     self other
name  sdf    sd
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [self, other]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [self, other]
Index: []
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6
       self other
name  hjfff    kl
age      15     6

is there any way I can beautify this format ?
with different columns and rows I have tried using merge and inner join , code -
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='id',how='inner')
print(df)

output
   id name_x  age_x name_y  age_y
0   1   asqw      1     as      4
1   2    sdf      2     sd      2
2   3     df      3     df      3
3   6  hjfff     15     kl      6

how can i compare _x with _y columns , any suggestions ?

Please show your code. I think we just need to add a pre-processing step, so if you provide your code, then we don't need to write everything from scratch.

Why is there a dot for each part of the output "sixth" column?

@wjandrea Removed dot.

Hi, you updated your question with an improved version of your own attempt. While it's admirable in itself that you continue trying, you did already receive an answer - mine ;) - that tries to show you how you can get to a df.compare output based on a trivial example of two dfs. Could you explain why my answer does not satisfy your requirements? Have you tried the code on your csv files? Is it not working? Do you want a different end result?

A direct comparison is not going to be possible due to, as you stated, differences in row and column count. So, you're going to need to write some functions to do this processing manually. My initial impression/workflow would be something akin to:

Generate a list of ID's present across the two data sets. You would only need the set of all unique values, as opposed to a list that would contain duplicates. You can achieve this in pandas/dataframe by casting your id column, such as set(list(dataframe['id column name goes here'])) and finding the intersection of two results (Best way to find the intersection of multiple sets?)

Now that you have a set of ID's to iterate through, you need to iterate through them and compare (*) your rows in each file. Here's a good thread on how to pull rows based on a conditional (in this case, ID  =X): How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?

You'll need some sort of helper method (*) to do the comparing. How you implement that is up to you, but I would imagine it would be formatted as compare([list of rows that share an ID]) --> new row containing set of all present headers, and comma delimtied entries for duplicate header/row values. This will be the bulk of the work, as it will be the core logic for producing the final dataframe.

Assuming you are storing these newly computed rows somewhere, you'll need to construct those into a new dataframe. Alternatively, generate a list of all headers at the beginning, spawn a new dataframe with those headers, and populate that new dataframe as you iterate down the ID values. Note that all rows you generate from the helper method will need to have all the headers present in the final export - otherwise pandas will throw a fit.

Export your new dataframe to file of your choosing.


Cheers, and good luck!

You can use pd.concat with keys parameter to get your data into the correct shape for df.compare:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

old = """id,one,two,three
0,1,2,3
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5"""

new = """id,one,two,four
3,1,2,3
1,1,3,4
2,3,4,6"""

keys = ['old', 'new']

df = (pd.concat([pd.read_csv(StringIO(c), index_col=0) for c in [old, new]], 
                keys=keys, axis=0)
      .pipe(lambda x: x[x.index.droplevel(0).duplicated(keep=False)])
      .unstack(0)
      .swaplevel(axis=1)
      )

df['old'].compare(df['new'], result_names=tuple(keys), keep_shape=True)

Output:
    one      two     three     four     
    old  new old new   old new  old  new
id                                      
1   2.0  1.0 NaN NaN   4.0 NaN  NaN  4.0
2   NaN  NaN NaN NaN   5.0 NaN  NaN  6.0

I.e., this means:

Column 'one': id 1 has a difference (2.0 vs 1.0)
Column 'two': no differences
Column 'three': only in old
Column 'four': only in new

Explanation / Intermediates

Use a list comprehension to read both csv files with pd.read_csv and pass it to pd.concat with axis=0. Add keys=['old','new'] to prepend an index level with the source. I.e., intermediate:

# pd.concat(..., keys=keys, axis=0)

        one  two  three  four
    id                       
old 0     1    2    3.0   NaN # NaNs for 'four' missing in `old` 
    1     2    3    4.0   NaN
    2     3    4    5.0   NaN
new 3     1    2    NaN   3.0 # NaNs for 'three' missing in `new`
    1     1    3    NaN   4.0
    2     3    4    NaN   6.0


We only want duplicate id values (1 and 2 values in index level 1). Use df.pipe to work with the result of the previous step, and apply boolean indexing.
Reduce the MultiIndex to a normal Index with df.index.droplevel and chain pd.index.duplicated with keep=False to get True for all duplicates.
Next, use df.unstack to add the keys (index level 0) as a second level to the column labels.
Since we actually need the keys as the first level, chain df.swaplevel. We now have:

# df

   old new old new   old   new  old  new
   one one two two three three four four
id                                      
1    2   1   3   3   4.0   NaN  NaN  4.0
2    3   3   4   4   5.0   NaN  NaN  6.0


This we can feed to df.compare easily. Adding the keys via result_names makes it easy to see the source of the column. keep_shape=True makes sure you see all the columns. With False, it would drop column 'two' since it has 0 differences.

